# How to compute a balanced k-partition of a weighted, undirected graph in NetworkX?

Tags: graph, networkx, partition

Given a connected, weighted, and undirected graph `G` with `ku` nodes in total, is there a functionality in NetworkX to compute a balanced k-partition of `G`? In particular, I need a functionality similar to [`kernighan_lin_bisection()`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.community.kernighan_lin.kernighan_lin_bisection.html) which provides a 2-partition for `G`, but for a general `k>2`.

Thanks!

I have tested [`kernighan_lin_bisection()`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.community.kernighan_lin.kernighan_lin_bisection.html) extensively, and it works great for my needs for `k=2`. I am now trying to find a general solution for computing a balanced k-partitioning of the graph, for `k>2`.  I found the function [`planted_partition_graph()`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.generators.community.planted_partition_graph.html) which also provides a k-partition. However, based on my understanding, it requires a connection probability for nodes within and outside the groups, rather than working directly with the edge weights. Hence, I am looking for something that is a general case of [`kernighan_lin_bisection()`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.community.kernighan_lin.kernighan_lin_bisection.html).